# In Window Application After making exe file xml files are access denied to write

Tags: c#, windows

I have done one windows application, here i am storing some data in xml file.

And also i want to update that xml file to update the details.

All things are going fine in Project, When i make exe file build. Installed in system, unable to write that file.
I am not able to find that reason, 
in project i gave full access permission to that file.

Comment: What version of Windows?  Where is the XML file?  If it is in program files, it is likely subject to UAC.  You can verify that by running as administrator and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Are you using a source control system that sets a file to read-only when it is checked in?

Comment: Not that running as Administrator is the right answer: if this is the problem, you should put the file somewhere that a normal user can write to (such as AppData).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where the XML file is located, you need to give it administrator privileges. You can do that by adding a manifest file to the project and modify the `RequestExecutionLevel` tag to `RequireAdministrator`.